# Puppeteer two forms click the second submit button

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to complete a simple webform, however the page has two forms and for each form a submit button:

```
<input type="image" img="" src="../graphics/button_search.gif" width="121" height="39" border="0">
```

So basically it is the following situation:

```html
<FORM NAME=form1 METHOD=POST ACTION="https://URI1">
    <FONT SIZE=2 FACE="verdana, arial, helvetica">
    <B>Search by E-mail Address</B> (recommended):</FONT>
    <TABLE WIDTH=574 CELLPADDING=3 CELLSPACING=2 BORDER=0>
    <TR>
        <TD WIDTH=50% BGCOLOR="#ffffcc" VALIGN=TOP><FONT SIZE=2 FACE="verdana, arial, helvetica">
        <B>Enter the E-mail Address:</B><BR></FONT> 
        <INPUT Name=vs_email value="" size=25></FONT></TD> 
    </TR> 
    </TABLE>
<TR>
     <TD ALIGN=RIGHT><INPUT type="image" IMG SRC="button_search_green.gif" WIDTH=121 HEIGHT=39 border=0 ></TD> 
</TR>
</FORM>

<FORM NAME=form2 METHOD=POST ACTION="https://URI2">
    <FONT SIZE=2 FACE="verdana, arial, helvetica">
    <B>Search by name</B> (not recommended):</FONT>
    <TABLE WIDTH=574 CELLPADDING=3 CELLSPACING=2 BORDER=0>
    <TR>
        <TD WIDTH=50% BGCOLOR="#ffffcc" VALIGN=TOP><FONT SIZE=2 FACE="verdana, arial, helvetica">
        <B>Enter the name:</B><BR></FONT> 
        <INPUT Name=vs_name value="" size=25></FONT></TD> 
    </TR> 
    </TABLE>
<TR>
     <TD ALIGN=RIGHT><INPUT type="image" IMG SRC="button_search_green.gif" WIDTH=121 HEIGHT=39 border=0 ></TD> 
</TR>
</FORM>
```

Now how can I make sure puppeteer clicks on the SECOND search button.
If I use the follwing code it presses the first one:

```
    const button = await page.$('input[type="image"]');
    await button.click();
```

Any suggestions how I can do a count on the input type="image" and select the second one?

Thanks

Maarten

Comment: `page.$('form[name=form2] input[type=image]')`?

Comment: Excellent Chris, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to expand your CSS selector a little in order to make it unique. What you need to do is use the following selector:

```
const button = await page.$('form[name="form2"] > input[type="image"]');
await button.click();
```

That should do the trick!