# Multi forms click only one button puppeteer

Tags: html, forms, puppeteer

My question is very similar with this but different situation ->

[Puppeteer two forms click the second submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51180760/puppeteer-two-forms-click-the-second-submit-button)

```
<button class="butn" type="submit">Next</button>
```

What should I do in order to refer which form since the forms only get data-id property instead of name?

```
<form class="eGHLloginForm" data-id="loginStep1">
<button class="butn" type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
```

```
<form class="eGHLloginForm" data-id="loginStep2">
<button class="butn" type="submit">Log IN</button>
</form>
```

I used this way, did not work

```
 const button = await page.$('form[data-id="loginStep1"] >button[type=submit]');
button.click();
```

Comment: Okay I just found out the answer it should be 
const button = await page.$('form[data-id="loginStep1"]  button[type=submit]');

Comment: I see many developers are on Selenium. Hmm.